# Change Django Default Language

Tags: python, django, translation, django-i18n

I've been developing a web application in English, and now I want to change the default language to German.

I tried changing the language code and adding the **locale** directory with all the translations, but Django still shows everything in English. I also want all my table names to be in German along with the content in the templates.

I also tried **Locale Middleware** and also [this repo](https://github.com/yifaneye/django-default-language) for a **custom middleware** but it still doesn't work.

Not to mention, Django changes the default language of the admin panel, but my field and table names remain English.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'language.DefaultLanguageMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATH = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
)
```

Here is my **locale directory**:

[image]

This is how I use translation in my **templates**:

```
{% load i18n static %} 

{% translate "Single User" %}
```

This is how I have defined my **models**:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Facility(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
  
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('Facilities')
```

Comment: Have you tried navigating in an incognito tab? LANGUAGE_CODE sets the default language, but that is the last place the middleware checks. It looks at the HTTP requests's django_language cookie and the Accepts-Language header before falling back to LANGUAGE_CODE. (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference )

Comment: yes I also tried loading it in incognito, but the table names and fields are still in english. @tonymke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out everything is just right, and the only thing that messed things up was a typo in **LOCALE_PATHS**.

settings.py:

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (    # notice the S which was forgotten
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')
)
```